# RSS aggregator to be used with cron for downloading feeds in background?

Tags: linux, rss, bash

I would like to find a command line RSS aggregator that I can put in my crontab, so it downloads feeds locally.

The purpose is that I would like to download the feeds locally, so I can use standard Linux utils such as `grep` on the feeds.

## Question

Does anyone know of a command line RSS aggregator?

Comment: Basically, RSS works over HTTP. So you can use `wget` to retrieve it. I don't use RSS, so I don't know what an aggregator is. I think of it as something that combines multiple RSSes from different days into one file. Do you really need that when you're doing it on a cronjob basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [RawDog](http://offog.org/code/rawdog/) which is a Python 2.7 based command line RSS feed aggregator specifically designed to be run from cron.

For Python 3 there is [RawDog-Py3](https://github.com/echarlie/rawdog-py3) which is a port of RawDog.

It is:

- cross platform, free & open source.
- supports templating & customisation
- has lots of plug-in components

Comment: See also [echarlie/rawdog-py3: Port of rawdog to Python3](https://github.com/echarlie/rawdog-py3)

Comment: @xebeche Thanks for pointing that out - added to answer.